# Автозагрузка .py скрипта на Linux

Tags: python, orange-pi

Друзья всем привет, купил себе Orangepi чтоб сделать с него сервер для телеграм ботов,
мне нужно чтоб боты сами запускались после перезагрузки устройства, я пробовал много способов но хоть както помог только один через:
`sudo crontab -e`
я туда записал это:

```
@reboot python3 /home/orangepi/bots/weather_bot/weather_bot.py &
@reboot python3 /home/orangepi/bots/echo_bot/main.py &
```

вроде помогло думал я но прошло пару часов и боты перестали работать, и так было дальше когда я перезагружал устройство они вроде работали, проходит пару часов и все боты неактивны что делать?

Comment: Для начала нужно выяснить, что же происходит: падает скрипт, отваливается сеть или устройство уходит в спячку. Выяснив причину можно будет думать о решении. В качестве костыля: попробовать обернуть в бесконечный цикл

Comment: а как сделать цикл и где?

Comment: в коде скриптов `while True: main()`, где `main()` - функция, в которой расположен код. Это не поможет, если скрипты падают по исключительной ситуации(Exception/Error)

Comment: Отслеживайте логи

Comment: И укажите ОС, установленную на устройстве

Comment: debian server    !!

Comment: Когда боты "отвалятся" в следующий раз, подключитесь по `ssh` и проверьте, запущены ли они. Для этого можно посмотреть в списке процессов `ps aux | grep bots`

Comment: статья на тему как добавить свой сервис https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/255845/

Comment: скорее всего устройство само переходит в спячку, как отключить авто выкл?

Comment: Нужна дополнительная информация. Уточните пожалуйста модель устройства. Установлена ли на устройстве какая либо графическая оболочка? Если да, то какая. Каким образом выполнено подключение к локальной сети?

Comment: Отключение сна https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend

Comment: Я уже сделал сервисы для ботов!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант, если у Вас есть systemd

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/<your_bot_name>.service
```

Туда копируете вот такой текст заменив текст в  <> на ваши параметры:

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=<YOUR BOT DESCRIPTION>
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=<имя пользователя от которого вы запускаете скрипты>
Group=<группа пользователя от которого вы запускаете скрипты>

Environment=PYTHONPATH=</full/path/to/directory/with/your/script> 
WorkingDirectory=</full/path/to/directory/with/your/script>
ExecStart=</full/path/to/python> </full/path/to/your/script>
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

**Далее:**
`Ctrl+X, y` для сохранения файла юнита который только что создали

**Затем**

```bsh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start <your_bot_name>.service
sudo systemctl status <your_bot_name>.service
# если все норм и юнит запустился...
sudo systemctl enable <your_bot_name>.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну это довольно просто.
В случае, если на апельсине стоит что-то убунтуподобное, то работает на sysnemd. Делаем так:

1. **systemctl enable rc-local**
2. в файле /etc/rc.local прописываем(ваши скрипты должны иметь права на запуск)

```bsh
sudo -u orangepi /home/orangepi/bots/weather_bot/weather_bot.py &
sudo -u orangepi /home/orangepi/bots/echo_bot/main.py &
```

3. пишем простейший скрипт /home/orangepi/testbot.sh(он тоже должен быть исполняемым)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if ps ax | grep python | grep -vq grep
then
  echo "python is already running"
  exit 0
else
  echo "starting python"
  sudo -u orangepi /home/orangepi/bots/weather_bot/weather_bot.py &
sudo -u orangepi /home/orangepi/bots/echo_bot/main.py &
  echo "ok"
fi
```

4. в crontab добавляем

```bsh
*/10 * * * * /home/orangepi/testbot.sh #проверка каждые 10 минут
```

Для openrc(что мне привычней) несколько иначе.

1. sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/local /etc/runlevels/default/local #ну не люблю я все эти rc-update
2. в файле /etc/local.d/startup.start (должен быть исполняемым) пишем:

```bsh
sudo -u orangepi /home/orangepi/bots/weather_bot/weather_bot.py &
sudo -u orangepi /home/orangepi/bots/echo_bot/main.py &
```

3. а далее все тоже самое с crontab, как написал выше.

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно использовать для запуска `flock` - программа которая позволяет запускать только один процесс.
Для использования достаточно добавить задание в cron:

```bsh
* * * * * user flock /var/lock/weather_bot.lock python3 /home/orangepi/bots/weather_bot/weather_bot.py
```

Запуск задания будет происходить каждую минуту, но пока процесс первого запущенного экземпляра не будет завершен, следующие процессы не будут запущены. Т.е. случился "краш" скрипта или его логическое завершение, то в течении минуты запустится новый экземпляр. Так же можно поставить таймаут ожидания, для мгновенного запуска, ключ `-w`.
Поставим значение на ожидание 58секунд:

```bsh
* * * * * user flock -w58 /var/lock/weather_bot.lock python3 /home/orangepi/bots/weather_bot/weather_bot.py
```

flock будет ожидать 58 секунд до завершения текущего процесса и если запущенный процесс завершится, то будет запущен новый экземпляр, максимальный лаг между остановкой и запуском новой версии будет ~2 секунды.

---

Файл дескриптора `/var/lock/{имя}.lock` для каждого скрипта должен быть свой