# Резмещение и запуск бота на сервер

Tags: telebot

Всем привет, написал телеграм бота, теперь нужно закинуть его на сервер и запустить, с этим возникли проблемы, так как я новичок в том то не могу его туда загрузить и запустить из-за неумения работать с линукс консолью. моя ОС: Windows x64. Скиньте пожалуйста годную статью или пошаговую инструкцию как это сделать, я почитал статьи и установил на сервер всё в соответствии со статьями, но с установкой бота и запуском его на сервере возникли проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Изучите как работает systemd и через него запускайте бота, вот статейка об этом: [Автозагрузка .py скрипта на Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1167196/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-py-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-linux)